# Igraph problems: i can not import a graph file(;graphml) with my igragh

Tags: python, ipython, igraph, graphml

I have a problem with my igraph and I'll ask your help.

When I entered:

```
g = Graph.Read_GraphML("apk.graphml")
```

I get a warning

> **main**:1: RuntimeWarning: unsupported attribute type (not string and not numeric) at src/attributes.c:507

And when i try to print my graph `g` ,i only see one node

```
print g

IGRAPH D--- 1 0 --

attr: d6 (v), description (v), id (v)**
```

Here you have the image of a part of my file (apk.graphml)

[image]